# Open workbooks have been flushed by Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I had a lot of open worksheets in the snowflake datawarehouse but now I don't see any.
How do I recover those worksheets?
I'm hoping there would be a provision folder for the same on the local computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on the small arrow on the top left and check under `Recent worksheets`

[image]

Also, your worksheets should be stored under **worksheet_data** (run `ls @~/worksheet_data` to list them).

Answer (score 0):

worksheets are actually stored in the user stage, and users can directly modify this stage, so this scenario is possible where users have actually deleted the contents of their user stage and lost worksheets that way.

In order to check if there are worksheets in the user stage, run the below in a new worksheet.

ls @~

If you see the worksheets, then open a new case to the support to get the scripts that can be run to view the contents of the worksheet and copy them to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once, if you contact Snowflake support they will link you to a document which describes how to recover the workbooks.