# Snowflake: Worksheet1 was not saved because saving would overwrite new changes on the server

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I received an prompt from snowflake reading

> *Worksheet1 was not saved because saving would overwrite new changes on the server. Please decide what to do next:

It provides two options,

> a) Overwrite Changes
>   b) Save to new worksheet.

**Q:** What changes to the server? is there a way to see that? Is this just regarding Worksheets?

**Q:** What is the safest option, New Worksheet?

Comment: The error is most common when you have the same worksheet open in another browser tab and you start making edits. New worksheet is safest, and then you can just double-check if other tabs are open with the same worksheet.

Comment: Meant to follow back up there. Thanks @SuzyLockwood I had just clicked **New Worksheet** from what I can tell it was just referring to worksheets. No other changes were made. I was just being paranoid since I'm still very new to snowflake

Comment: No worries!  I know I wouldn't want to lose my worksheets either on accident.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with new worksheet, however if you ever loose a worksheet there is a really cool feature that shows all historical worksheets associated with the account/role you are logged into here:

Click on the drop arrow next to the furthest to the right worksheet > Select "Open Worksheet"

All of the worksheets that were closed can be opened again.

Comment: Regarding what changes on the server, this post may be helpful -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174883/open-workbooks-have-been-flushed-by-snowflake/59176189#59176189

Comment: Meant to follow back up there. Thanks @squadflake I had just clicked **New Worksheet** from what I can tell it was just referring to worksheets. No other changes were made. I was just being paranoid since I'm still very new to snowflake